# Returning json objects from a WebSerice in an Ajax Response

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, response, webmethod

I'm trying to return json objects from a Webservice (ASP.NET WebForms application) into an Ajax success response. Although data is being returned in the Webservice, no data is making it to the Ajax response.

Here's the WebService:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Images> GetImageObj()
{
    List<Images> all = new List<Images>();
    Images infoObjs = new Images();
    ImageLoading iload = new ImageLoading();
    DataTable dtImages = iload.GetData();
    foreach (DataRow row in dtImages.Rows)
    {
        infoObjs.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["FILE_ID"].ToString());
        Byte[] bytes = ((Byte[])row["THUMBNAIL_CONTENT"]);
        infoObjs.ImageURI = iload.GetImage(bytes);
        all.Add(infoObjs);
    }            
    return all;
}

public class Images
{
    public List<Images> imgObjs;
    public string ImageURI;
    public int ID;
}
```

Here's the Ajax Callback function:

```
function AjaxCall() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataArr = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: '../WebService1.asmx/GetImageObj',
            method: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{'aray':" + JSON.stringify(dataArr) + "}",  
            success: function (response) {   
            //No data is making it here:
                var getData = JSON.parse(response.d); 
                alert(getData);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

UPDATE: @Julian's answer fixed my issue. However, I had to add the following to my webconfig to accommodate the large data from the encoded image URI:

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <!-- Update this value to change the value to a larger value that can accommodate your JSON Strings -->
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="86753090" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return a `string`, but serialize the object in JSON using the `Json.NewtonSoft` library.

Also add the `[ScriptService]` tag on the service to be consumed from Ajax:

**C# Code:**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetImageObj()
    {
        List<Images> all = new List<Images>();

        Images infoObjs = new Images();
        ImageLoading iload = new ImageLoading();
        DataTable dtImages = iload.GetData();
        foreach (DataRow row in dtImages.Rows)
        {
            infoObjs.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["FILE_ID"].ToString());
            Byte[] bytes = ((Byte[])row["THUMBNAIL_CONTENT"]);
            infoObjs.ImageURI = iload.GetImage(bytes);
            all.Add(infoObjs);
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(all, Formatting.Indented);
    }
}
```

**AJAX Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var dataArr = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: '../WebService.asmx/GetImageObj',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{}",  
            success: function (response) {   
                //No data is making it here:
                var getData = JSON.parse(response.d); 
                console.log(getData);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer solved my problem although I had to update webconfig to accommodate the large data (see my updated post). I was getting 500 internal server errors until this was resolved. Thanks!